# npm start gives an error and doesn't start

Tags: node.js, npm, electron

I get an error when running npm start. It was working fine and then suddenly it started doing this. I have rebooted to make sure there are no hanging processes. I did a npm cache verify. Here is the log it provides.

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.12.0
3 info using node@v12.13.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle electron-quick-start@1.0.0~prestart: electron-quick-start@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle electron-quick-start@1.0.0~start: electron-quick-start@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle electron-quick-start@1.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle electron-quick-start@1.0.0~start: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\dillon_vance\git\backup-restore\node_modules\.bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\1E\NomadBranch\;C:\Program Files\Dell\Dell Data Protection\Encryption\;C:\PSTools\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\dillon_vance\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Users\dillon_vance\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\dillon_vance\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle electron-quick-start@1.0.0~start: CWD: C:\Users\dillon_vance\git\backup-restore
10 silly lifecycle electron-quick-start@1.0.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'electron .' ]
11 silly lifecycle electron-quick-start@1.0.0~start: Returned: code: 2147483651  signal: null
12 info lifecycle electron-quick-start@1.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: electron-quick-start@1.0.0 start: `electron .`
13 verbose stack Exit status 2147483651
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:210:5)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
14 verbose pkgid electron-quick-start@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\dillon_vance\git\backup-restore
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17763
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v12.13.0
19 verbose npm  v6.12.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 2147483651
22 error electron-quick-start@1.0.0 start: `electron .`
22 error Exit status 2147483651
23 error Failed at the electron-quick-start@1.0.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 2147483651, true ]
```

I don't have anymore ideas. I googled the error code, but didn't find a solution for my issue. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your project has been configured incorrectly. I assume you are following the instructions [here](https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start). Please make a new directory and follow the instructions from scratch and list what steps you took.

Comment: This is the guide I was following.
https://xainey.github.io/2017/powershell-electron-demo/
The steps that were taken match with the link you gave. Like I said, it has been working fine, then I turned on my laptop this morning and I was getting this error.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same issue and tried the same trouble shooting steps. Using the Quick-Start guide electron provides is not working. I've set up numerous Electron projects before too.